# Why did past Shaktimaan orbit around present Shaktimaan?

Tags: shaktimaan

Once, Kilvish was enslaving a large group of people. Shaktimaan appeared to stop him. Kilvish stepped into a box. Shaktimaan followed him into that box and found that it contained merely an image of Kilvish. That box turned out to be a Time Machine. Kilvish didn't hesitate to activate it, and he sent Shaktimaan into the future after locking the Time Machine.
([Episode 225 @6:45](https://youtu.be/VzDayCuBO2U))

Geeta then asked Dwija for help. She travelled to the past using Dwija's Time Machine and picked up the past version of Shaktimaan. In the the past, she managed to find the Shaktimaan of her time. He was trapped in the time machine floating in outer space.

As they approached that time machine, Dwija told past Shaktimaan to exit the Time Machine to free the imprisoned "future" Shaktimaan, because only he could survive being exposed to vaccum. When past Shaktimaan exited, he started to revolve around his future version.
([Episode 230 @13:30](https://youtu.be/k4VxC9wU3Q0))

Why did past Shaktimaan started to orbit his future version?

Comment: Reasons of downvote would be nice..

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvotes. In case it was readability, I tried editing your question a bit. Feel free to change or even roll back if you think I made mistakes. If someone is downvoting because this is an obscure (in the US, at least) title, well... I think that would be a terrible reason to downvote. Personally, I'm glad you're asking Shaktimaan questions, because after reading up on it, it sounds like something I'd really like to watch.

Comment: @Beofett Time Machine was locked in the sense nobody could exit or enter. Its control was on separate device which was in hands of Kilvish. Other than this, all edits were fine (impressive)... Thanks!

Comment: @Beofett You can find Shaktimaan episodes on internet (check YouTube too). But, to understand, you'll have to learn Hindi (unless you know a real-time translator). Shaktimaan was dubbed in many other Indian language, but never in English.. :(

Comment: @SachinShekhar If it's legally on youtube, then maybe link to it? Your text description doesn't help anyone interested in answering find this particular episode.

Comment: @Tacroy 1. It's not legally there. 2. That particular episode no. isn't in my mind. I watched that episode in late 90s. :(

Comment: @SachinShekhar Unless there is a ton of profanity in it, the few phrases I know of Hindi are unlikely to be of much help :P

Comment: @SachinShekhar It might help if you noted which episode of *Shaktimaan* you’re referring to. At the moment, the question almost reads like a story in itself, instead of a description of a story supporting a question.